# How to find and uninstall the numpy duplicate versions

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, gpy

I am trying to install the library GPy. Although the installation is successful, I have a question on my numpy version.

GPy library can be found here https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy

The current version of my numpy is 1.9.3

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.9.3'
```

But when I perform `python setup.py install` for GPy, it refers to numpy 1.10.0. I checked in python 2.7/site-packages there only one version of numpy exist that too 1.9.3

```
Using /home/vinod/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Searching for scipy==0.16.0
Best match: scipy 0.16.0
Adding scipy 0.16.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/vinod/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Searching for numpy==1.10.0
Best match: numpy 1.10.0
Adding numpy 1.10.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/vinod/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for GPy==0.8.8
vinod@vinod-Lenovo-G580:~/GPy$
```

Since it's referring to another version am getting error like

```
File"__init__.pxd", line 155, in init GPy.util.linalg_cython (GPy/util/linalg_cython.c:4238)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Could anyone tell me how to find and remove the numpy 1.10.0 ?

Comment: I'm getting this same issue when trying to install pandas via pip. I have numpy 1.9.2 installed, but pandas reports that it's trying to use numpy 1.10.0.

Comment: Are you using anaconda, if not please try it, it includes almost all necessary libraries including pandas.

Answer (score 0):

From the [conda FAQ](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/faq.html#pinning-packages):

```
conda update numpy --no-pin
```

Comment: vinod@vinod-Lenovo-G580:~$ conda update numpy --no-pin
Fetching package metadata: ....
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/vinod/anaconda:
#
numpy                     1.9.3                   py27_p0  [mkl]

But still am getting the same error.

Comment: What about `conda remove numpy` followed by `conda install numpy`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following steps and it works but still I don't know how.

1. I opened the setup.py and changed the numpy condition from `numpy >= 1.7` to `numpy <=1.9.3`
2. Then I performed the `python setup.py install`
3. Then I uninstalled GPy using `pip uninstall GPy`
4. Again I installed GPy but using `pip install GPy`. Note: in previous steps I used git and installed separately.
5. This time it upgraded my numpy to 1.10.0 during installation and got installed successfully
6. Finally now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

1. python Packeges
2. installed
3. select the library you want to unistall
4. "delate" by selecting t[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0J2U.png)he menu on the right

Comment: It's not a general solution, namely, IDE specific.